# Nodejs (express) is posting twice in production

Tags: node.js, express

Got such a wierd error

When I make a post in production it makes two post

```
1|rest-backend  | POST /api/person 200 - ms - 355
1|rest-backend  | POST /api/person 200 - ms - 355
```

The client only sends one. Also tried from postman so it is not frontend error.

Now the wierd part. It only happens in production! In dev environment it only posts once as expected.

No odd code on backend. Just a mongoose().create();

What can it be? How do I debug this?

Comment: Does your post handler has return statement? please share a snippet of your `post` handler.

Comment: It did not. It also had a next(). This solved the issue. Thank you. Wierd though it worked in dev environment.